# how do I have dialogs in angularJS? $modal?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to follow [this blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service) about implementing a modal dialog in angularJS.  I am using angularJS 1.6.

I've added angular bootstrap by adding "ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js" (I've also tried "ui-bootstrap-2.5.0.js") into my includes.   When I reference $modal in an angular service or controller, I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <-
```

My service looks like this, pretty much a copy from the blog:

```
var servicesInstance = angular.module('obdPortletApp');  

servicesInstance.service('ModalService', ['$modal',
    function ($modal) {
```

So I am not sure what is missing.  Perhaps that blog is wrong, out of date, etc....

Google yields an overwhelming number of hits.  Every one has a different implementation, different library to download.   Quite frankly, its rather frustrating for something that should be straight forward.  Any direction on a simple why to implement modal dialog would be appreciated.

btw bootstrap isn't a requirement.  Whatever is easier....

Thnx
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog you are referencing is out of date. Several months ago, UI-Bootstrap introduced a breaking change that added prefixes to their services and components.

In your case, you want $uibModal instead of $modal.

```
var servicesInstance = angular.module('obdPortletApp');  

servicesInstance.service('ModalService', ['$uibModal',
    function ($uibModal) {
```

Please refer to the current UI-Bootstrap documentation for their modals.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal

Comment: Thank you.  That link will be useful as well.